# Private Key has no fund

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key-import, import, funds

I tried to import my private key from the BTC Core Wallet into another wallet because it doesn't work anymore, it says that there is no fund, even if it is 100%, as I can see on the Explorer.

I really need help. My Btc Core wallet is not running, but I was able to open a new wallet with my Dat.dat file and check my private key, it's all correct.

Comment: is there something i missing ? Privatkey i got, but my Btc not...

Comment: Did you export with `dumpprivkey`? The `wallet.dat` can only be recognized by Core.

Comment: yes i did, i get so confused why it's has no fund ? it seems like a wrong key, it says not spendable not match with public key, and if i import without the Public Adresse it says no fund on it. i try now to synchronised BTC Core aigain, but it will take so long. thatwhy i tryed to import the privatkey on two other wallet, but both doesn't work. On explorer the funds are still there, no transaction happen.

Comment: If it's says "not spendable" then it's very likely that you've been scammed and they made your Bitcoin Core see their money that you can't spend as your money. Maybe that's the case? You can't import it because you don't have the private key for the address.

Comment: thats very odd, how ? my adresse still remain the Balance on blockchainexplorer, but the Privatkey seems 0 Balance. As far i know you can't change a private Key unless you change the Adresse.

Comment: Maybe the private key you have isn't the private key which is needed to generate that address? Or maybe you should use `listunspent` and see if `spendable` is true.

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean by that listunspent and see if spendable is true, by the way thank you for all your answer

Comment: When you imported the privkey to a new wallet, did it create the same addresses that bitcoin-core did? Perhaps this is just an issue with address type? It seems unlike ya scammer would have you import an address to core, as that would require a chain rescan, etc. Normally that scam is used in conjunction with the blockchain.info wallet

Comment: no it did not create the same adresse, as far i know this is common. the only i worried after the crash of my btccore wallet there was a popup from "windows" what i click, afterwards when i reopen there was another popup Assertion failed expression pindexwalk.

Comment: i forgot to mension the window pop up made a rescan i guess

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem may be that the new wallet derived a different type of  address from your private key.

Normal wallet function will present you with a new address each time you receive coins. Each of those addresses will have an associated private key, that needs to be used to spend the funds. Note that the same private key is not used to derive multiple addresses in a wallet, there is a 1:1 relationship for private keys and addresses.

So when you want to import that private key to a new wallet, you need to make sure the new wallet derives the correct address from it (ie, the same one your original wallet did, when you originally received the payment), otherwise the new wallet is showing a different address then it will not show your funds, since it is looking in the wrong place.

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92907/how-many-possible-addresses-per-bitcoin-private-key) has a bit of info about different address types.

As a first step, compare the first characters of the address that holds the funds, and the address that the new wallet generated. If they are not the same (eg the original is `3...` and the new wallet is `bc1...`), then you will need to either instruct the new wallet to generate the correct type of address, or if this is not possible, you will need to find a different wallet that is capable of doing so.

Note: if your bitcoin-core wallet is fully synced, you can run the command `bitcoin-cli listunspent`, to get a list of UTXOs that the wallet is keeping track of. You can look through the list to confirm the balance of specific addresses using this command, to ensure you are attempting to export the correct private key.

Answer (score 0):

Redo the import. Start via file > new/restore, enter a unique filename and click next to begin the process. This time prepend one of the following to the private key:
•   p2wpkh: if the address in question begins with bc1
•   p2wpkh-p2sh: if the address in question begins with 3
For example:
p2wpkh-p2sh: KwZfCiAcXNz………………ntA6bXCQrG6JbxMy