# What are the formats of a private key?

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery, wallet-import-format

I copied my private key to a file and I can't remember what the string begins with. Can you help me by giving me the different types of private key: number of characters and and with which characters the private keys start. This is a bitcoin key from 2011/2012.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why bitcoin private key WIF format always be started in K or L?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95648/why-bitcoin-private-key-wif-format-always-be-started-in-k-or-l)

Answer (score 1):

Ian's BIP39 site will show you an example of pretty much every coins private key format.  Technically these are WIF encoded private keys, but I assume these are what you mean.

- https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Answer (score 1):

> **[what are] the different types of private key: number of characters and and with which characters the private keys start.**

I have this note from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

| Decimal prefix | Hex | Example use | Leading symbol(s) | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 80 | Private key (WIF, uncompressed pubkey) | 5 | 5Hwgr3u458GLafKBgxtssHSPqJnYoGrSzgQsPwLFhLNYskDPyyA |
| 128 | 80 | Private key (WIF, compressed pubkey) | K or L | L1aW4aubDFB7yfras2S1mN3bqg9nwySY8nkoLmJebSLD5BWv3ENZ |
| 4 136 173 228 | 0488ADE4 | BIP32 private key | xprv | xprv9s21ZrQH143K24Mfq5zL5MhWK9hUhhGbd45hLXo2Pq2oqzMMo63o StZzF93Y5wvzdUayhgkkFoicQZcP3y52uPPxFnfoLZB21Teqt1VvEHx |
| 239 | EF | Testnet Private key (WIF, uncompressed pubkey) | 9 | 92Pg46rUhgTT7romnV7iGW6W1gbGdeezqdbJCzShkCsYNzyyNcc |
| 239 | EF | Testnet Private key (WIF, compressed pubkey) | c | cNJFgo1driFnPcBdBX8BrJrpxchBWXwXCvNH5SoSkdcF6JXXwHMm |
| 4 53 131 148 | 04358394 | Testnet BIP32 private key | tprv | tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPcsbCVeqqF1KVdH7gwDJbxbzpCxDUsoXHdb6SnTPY xdwSAKDC6KKJzv7khnNWRAJQsRA8BBQyiSfYnRt6zuu4vZQGKjeW4YF |

Comment: The question is about private keys but only six rows in the answer refer to private keys.

Comment: @Pranab: Good point, others removed.